# Spark parse and processing file parquet/json

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have some large data, in parquet format.
I'd like to use Spark in Scala to transform this file and save into json format.
My input file looks something like this:

```
a1,   a2,  b,  d,    c1,   c2,    c3,   e (header)
1,   null, 2, "1d", "abc", null, null,  7 (row1)
null, 3,   4, "2c", null,  null, "def", 9 (row2)
... more rows to follow
```

`a1` and `a2` are essentially the same column, for each row, only one of them is not null, the same applies for `c1`, `c2` and `c3`, and I'd like to process my input file with two transformations, the first one is to form the correct `a` and `c` column for each row and remove the null ones, so the output will look something like this:

```
a,  b,   d,   c,    e (header)
1,  2, "1d", "abc", 7 (row1)
3,  4, "2c", "def", 9 (row2)
... more rows to follow
```

The 2nd transformation that I'd like to do is: based on column `d`, if the value of column `d` falls into one set of values ("1d","12","a9","df"), I'd like to add one more value ("1f8") into this row, if not, add the other value ("d8n"), the output will look like this after the second transformation:

```
a,  b,   d,   c,    e,   f   (header)
1,  2, "1d", "abc", 7, "1f8" (row1)
3,  4, "2c", "def", 9, "d8n" (row2)
... more rows to follow
```

Note: column `f` is newly added based on the value of `d`.

Comment: can you tell how `f` has values 9 & 1 ?

Comment: those are just two completely separate values based on the value of column `d`, I've updated it to make it more clear. thanks

Comment: in first transformation, you have two `c` columns.. is that expected ?

Comment: good call, I've just updated it again. thanks

Comment: is it ok, if solution is in scala ?

Comment: that'd be perfect! I'm using Scala running in Zeppelin notebook. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Data

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+
|a1  |a2  |b  |d  |c1  |c2  |c3  |e  |
+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+
|1   |null|2  |4  |abc |null|null|7  |
|null|3   |4  |1  |null|null|def |9  |
+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+
```

First Transformation, applying `nvl` function to columns `a1`,`a2`,`c1`,`c2`,`c3` dynamic based length of the column name.

```
scala> val columns = (
    df
    .columns
    .filter(_.length > 1)
    .groupBy(c => c(0))
    .map(c => 
        if(c._2.length > 2) 
            s"${c._2.sliding(2).map(c => s"nvl(${c.head},${c.last})").mkString("nvl(",",",")")} as ${c._1}" 
        else 
            s"${c._2.sliding(2).map(c => s"nvl(${c.head},${c.last})").mkString} as ${c._1}"
        ) ++ 
    df.columns.filter(_.length == 1)
).toSeq
```

Above code will combine columns like below

```
columns: Seq[String] = List(nvl(a1,a2) as a, nvl(nvl(c1,c2),nvl(c2,c3)) as c, b, d, e)
```

```
scala> 
    df
    .selectExpr(columns:_*)
    .withColumn(
        "f",
        when(
            $"d".cast("int").isin(Seq(4,2,8,12):_*),
            lit("1f8")
        ).otherwise("d8n")
    ) // Second Transformation
    .show(false)
```

Final Output

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|a  |c  |b  |d  |e  |f  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|1  |abc|2  |4  |7  |1f8|
|3  |def|4  |1  |9  |d8n|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but I guess my description was misleading, I was trying to hide my business logic, so put the column names as those, in reality, they don't share any prefixes.., I've updated my OP again, apologies.

Comment: and for column `d`, it's not actually integers, those are `UUID`s. apologies and thanks again

Comment: logic is pretty simple, use `nvl` function. as per above question I have given one possible solution.

Comment: its upto you, how you want to apply `nvl` function to set of columns.

Comment: thanks @Srinivas, following your answer along with some other examples, I got it working: ```d.createOrReplaceTempView("ParquetTable")
val parkSQL = spark.sql("""select b, d, e, f, NVL(a1, a2) as a, NVL(c1, NVL(c2, c3)) as c from ParquetTable""")``` and then ```parkSQL.withColumn("f", when($"d".isin(Seq(4,2,8,12):_*),lit("1f8")).otherwise("d8n")).show(false)```, thanks a ton!